# "Encrypt the file list" option greyed out when creating ZIP file

Tags: encryption, archive, zip

I am fairly new to Ubuntu and frankly not very tech savvy. I am using Archive Manager 43.0 on Ubuntu 22.10. I want to encrypt some sensitive files, and I would really like it if the name of the files were encrypted too. My problem is when I compress my files to ZIP format and then head over to the "password" option, I can add my password, but the option to encrypt the files' names is greyed out and can't be toggled on.

[image: Picture of the problem]